# Yowsup authorization not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, whatsapp, yowsup

I recently tried implementing yowsup python client on my raspberry pi (running raspbian). I have downloaded all relevant libraries for yowsup and completed the 2 step registration process.

I took the sample layer.py and run.py files from the [yowsup github](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/Sample-Application) to make a simple echo bot.

When I try to run the run.py I am met with the following error:

Any help is much appreciated!

```
python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 20, in <module>
    stack.loop() #this is the program mainloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/stacks/yowstack.py", line 196, in loop
    asyncore.loop(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 216, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 156, in poll
    read(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 87, in read
    obj.handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 83, in read
    obj.handle_read_event()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 449, in handle_read_event
    self.handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/network/layer.py", line 102, in handle_read
    self.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/network/layer.py", line 110, in receive
    self.toUpper(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/stanzaregulator/layer.py", line 29, in receive
    self.processReceived()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/stanzaregulator/layer.py", line 49, in processReceived
    self.toUpper(oneMessageData)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/auth/layer_crypt.py", line 65, in receive
    self.toUpper(payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/coder/layer.py", line 35, in receive
    self.toUpper(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/logger/layer.py", line 14, in receive
    self.toUpper(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_control.py", line 44, in receive
    self.toUpper(protocolTreeNode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 189, in receive
    s.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_receive.py", line 44, in receive
    self.toUpper(protocolTreeNode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 76, in toUpper
    self.__upper.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 189, in receive
    s.receive(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/__init__.py", line 125, in receive
    recv(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.0-py2.7.egg/yowsup/layers/auth/layer_authentication.py", line 81, in handleFailure
    raise AuthError(nodeEntity.getReason())
yowsup.layers.auth.autherror.AuthError: not-authorized
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very similar issue, and I believe the problem is that the tutorial is out of date. There are now three Axolotl layers you have to include in your stack, instead of just the one [(see this commit)](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/commit/8cb3a84dc100ad7d688650d3db9e7ebafaddc3a7).

Where your stack would have looked like this:

```
layers = (
    EchoLayer,
    YowParallelLayer([YowAuthenticationProtocolLayer, YowMessagesProtocolLayer, YowReceiptProtocolLayer,
                      YowAckProtocolLayer]), YowAxolotlLayer
) + YOWSUP_CORE_LAYERS
```

It now has to look like this:

```
layers = (
    EchoLayer,
    YowParallelLayer([YowAuthenticationProtocolLayer, YowMessagesProtocolLayer, YowReceiptProtocolLayer,
                      YowAckProtocolLayer]), AxolotlReceivelayer, AxolotlSendLayer, AxolotlControlLayer,
) + YOWSUP_CORE_LAYERS
```

You'll need to add the following imports as well:

```
from yowsup.layers.axolotl import AxolotlSendLayer, AxolotlControlLayer, AxolotlReceivelayer
```

Please note that `AxolotlReceivelayer` has a lowercase 'L' in 'layer'. I think this was probably an oversight on the part of the Yowsup maintainers, since it's incongruous with the rest of their naming scheme. What I do is this:

```
from yowsup.layers.axolotl import AxolotlReceivelayer as AxolotlReceiveLayer
```

just so that I've got consistency in my code.